# Grouping Rows by User Entered List in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I want to create a report that takes rows from our CRM database and group them by a list of salespersons that is entered by the user.  The list of salespersons is not included in the database.

So, I want to divide up current accounts into equal groups (n=number of salespersons entered by user) depending on a list of salespersons defined by the user.  The list of salespersons could change every time in number and name.  The report then would be have groups named as the salespersons entered by the user.

In SQL, the NTILE function can be used to divide the rows into equal groups and I can create a command to do this in Crystal Reports, but how do I assign a varying list of names to each of the groups?

Thanks,

Sean

Comment: can you show NTILE function that you have written?

Comment: Can you draw out your goal in Excel and upload it? Sample tables and an example of how salepeople are entered by the user would be good too. I think you'll get a helpful answer to your question, but it's a little tricky to understand without more info

Comment: @Siva Here is the NTILE Function that I have written as a command in Crystal Reports: SELECT NTILE({?NumberSalesAssociates}) OVER (ORDER BY C.AccountNumber) AS CallList, *
FROM CUSTOMER C

Comment: @Jackson Attached is the sample of the report I would like to end up with after exporting from Crystal Reports to Excel.  The only table I need from the database is the Customer table.  The user would have to enter the names they want to divide up the report by.  I was wanting this to be done with and parameter in Crystal Reports.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/uzml3tmqt4ce1iy/Sample%20Report.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: @SMcHugh Sorry for the delay in response, was on the road for the week and a half. Give me a day or two to catch up on work and I'll revisit this with you, hopefully before the end of the week.

Comment: Sounds great.  Thank you, Sean

Comment: Checking in, back in action after multiple surprise re-formats on my box. It's been a fun week of Windows installations. Bumped your question with a vote. I'll look at it today and get back to it next week as well

Comment: Finally revisiting this. Let me know if you've solved it. Still trying to understand the goal. Your link in the comment above is broken, links to HTML code. Try taking a screenshot of a mock-up in Excel of what you want the report to look like after it is run. Upload the screenshot to tinyurl or something similar and link to it here.

Comment: Questions: Is the goal to *assign* a salesperson to each row? If so, is this a permanent assignment (one you wish to be reflected in your database), or is it an assignment you want only to be reported by Crystal (thus the assignments would change slightly with each run based on the number of rows in the table)?

Comment: My current understanding is this: You have a table of "things" (whether they be businesses, items, etc). You need a report that will request a user to input a list of salespeople. The rows of your table will then be evenly distributed (with no organization necessary, whatever is most straightforward, perhaps alphabetically ) amongst your salespeople. The output will indicate (by groupings of salespeople) which rows have been given to which salesperson.

Comment: Is the goal to assign a salesperson to each row? --> Yes      If so, is this a permanent assignment (one you wish to be reflected in your database), or is it an assignment you want only to be reported by Crystal (thus the assignments would change slightly with each run based on the number of rows in the table)? ---> not permanent, only in Crystal

Comment: My current understanding is this: You have a table of "things" (whether they be businesses, items, etc). You need a report that will request a user to input a list of salespeople. The rows of your table will then be evenly distributed (with no organization necessary, whatever is most straightforward, perhaps alphabetically ) amongst your salespeople. The output will indicate (by groupings of salespeople) which rows have been given to which salesperson.  --> You are exactly correct.

Comment: @Jackson correct.

Comment: Nice bump. I'll check it out when I have time.

Comment: In the meantime, try using a function for a conditional position (formula button in the size/position frame) in crystal reports similarly to how you would use the ntile function. Look to place the first one under column 1 using x coordinates. If you have 3 columns to divvy them up under, you could use an if statement to say if mod3=0 place under column 1, mod3=1, place under column 2, mod3 = 2 place under column 3.

Comment: whileprintingrecords will probably be your friend